# How to count dynamically orders of each month incrementally in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, array-formulas

I want to count orders for each month by incrementing each order and resetting them for the next month in a dynamic fashion, like this.
[image]

I tried [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) function to count the range of [`MONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en) but the out put is the count if all the range, Take a look at [the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aRIaAXyGk7cSbe1PMidwGBBksfv89y4qET-T1dAKfCY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your provided sheet try below formula-

```
=Arrayformula(IF(D2:D="",,COUNTIFS(D2:D, D2:D, ROW(D2:D), "<="&ROW(D2:D))))
```

Actually you do not need helping `Month` column. You can achieve your desired result directly using below formula.

```
=Arrayformula(IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIFS(Month(B2:B), Month(B2:B), ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @harun24hr that work perfectly, But I didn't understand how the ROW function is used. An explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ROW()` is comparing each row with previous rows of data and counting based on previous rows. So, when formula going down it is taking all previous rows as counting parameter.